# google+ login SDK not working

Tags: ios, authentication, google-plus

I am developing an iOS app. When I run the program for google+ login, after I hit the allow access button, this message is displayed.

> You've reached this page because we have detected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.
>   Please enable scripts and go back in your browser."

Also, I placed an NSlog for `GooglePlusSignInDelegate` method below:

```
(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error[A]: %@", error);
} else 
{    
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS!");
}
```

No log coming out. Does that mean I am not yet authorized in google+ login?

Comment: Resolved the issue already. I was not able to update the right bundleID when I added the Url type

Comment: Can you turn the comment into an answer? It might help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my own issue.

When I changed the bundle ID, I didn't update it in the URL type.

Here's how I updated the URL type:
Select the application target in the list of targets, then click the Info tab. Under the URL Types, be sure to indicate the right bundleID.